# One sided limit approachig from outside domain

Tags: calculus

Say I have a function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ for $x$ greater than or equal to $0$. If $x$ approaches $0$ from the left, can we say the limit exists? values less than $0$ arent even in the domain of our function and while its clear to see the function exists at $x=0$. I dont think we can evaluate for values outside the domain.

Comment: you are right. You can't have left limit in this case.

Comment: You should make that an answer @Kf-Sansoo , because it is.

Comment: The reason why I am confused is because I checked wolfram to see if it would agree, but it said the one-sided limit is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolfram probably is not restricting the range of $f$ to the real numbers as you are. If you define $f(x) = i\sqrt{-x}$ for $x < 0$, then indeed, $$\lim_{x\to0^-} f(x) = 0.$$

But this is a result of expanding the domain of $f$ to include the left side of zero. It is not a case of taking a limit from outside the domain.

For $x$ outside the domain of $f$, there is no such thing as $f(x)$, so there is nothing to take the limit of, and thus, no sensible way of defining such a limit.

Comment: Then we wouldnt say the limit does not exist right? Rather we would say "indeterminant" or "cannot be evauluated" or something along those lines?

Comment: We would say the limit is nonsensical. How do you take a "limit" of nothing? It would make as much sense to speak of "the limit of blue-eyed apples".